# Kafka input plugin 'Receive failed: Invalid response size' error

Tags: apache-kafka, fluent-bit

We use newest FluentBit with [Kafka input plugin](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/inputs/kafka) (different FluentBit with [Kafka output](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/outputs/kafka) is also responsible for producing to Kafka).
After some time we started seeing this error:
*Receive failed: Invalid response size 4020574 (0..4000000): increase receive.message.max.bytes (after 5ms in state UP, 4 identical error(s) suppressed)*.

Kafka plugin [sources](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit/blob/master/plugins/in_kafka/in_kafka.c#L246) show `fetch.max.bytes` and `receive.message.max.bytes` are overridden by `Buffer_Max_Size` from FluentBit [Kafka Input settings](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/inputs/kafka).

We tried to tweak [librdkafka properties](https://github.com/confluentinc/librdkafka/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md), but with no luck.
Increasing Buffer_Max_Size results in seeing similar errors for bigger values or with really huge values we exceeding polling max time.

```
[INPUT]
Name                                kafka
Tag                                 apps
Brokers                             ${KAFKA_BROKER_SERVER_LIST}
Topics                              ${TOPICS}
rdkafka.security.protocol           ssl
rdkafka.ssl.key.location            /secrets/secrets.private_key
rdkafka.ssl.certificate.location    /secrets/secrets.certificate
rdkafka.group.id                    apps
rdkafka.client.id                   apps
rdkafka.allow.auto.create.topics    true
rdkafka.auto.offset.reset           latest
```